# Asp.Net Web Framework for Asp.net 2.0 and Visual Studio 2005

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, asp.net-2.0, design-patterns, spring.net

I am working on re-factoring of an existing Asp.Net 2.0 web site. I am looking for a framework/pattern to modularise the application. As there is no WCSF for Visual Studio 2005 I can't use it and I also can not upgrade it to Visual Studio 2008 for reasons beyond my control.
I can use Mono-Rail but I would loose the existing controls functionality. Does any one know a good Framework/Pattern that can be used consistently across the modules on Asp.Net 2.0/Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to know about Spring.Net Web Framework which supports Asp.Net 2.0 and Visual Studio 2005. It has few good features like Two way Model Binding, Navigation support, Validation and DI Container. Only problem with Spring.Net is huge Xml files to define everything